# Swagger initialize db(gorm) connection on every db call

Tags: go, swagger, go-gorm

I have an API created with Swagger, that communicates with a Mariadb instance via gorm. I'm not pleased with how I'm handling the db connection module, and passing the the db handler around. How can I make this more robust and maybe incorporate interface, and always calling the `db.Open` function each time a make a db request.

Here is my config file created by Swagger

```
func configureAPI(api *operations.HairdooAPI) http.Handler {
    // configure the api here
    api.ServeError = errors.ServeError

    // Set your custom logger if needed. Default one is log.Printf
    // Expected interface func(string, ...interface{})
    //
    // Example:
    //api.Logger = log.Printf

    api.UseSwaggerUI()
    // To continue using redoc as your UI, uncomment the following line
    // api.UseRedoc()

    api.JSONConsumer = runtime.JSONConsumer()
    //api.UrlformConsumer = runtime.DiscardConsumer

    api.JSONProducer = runtime.JSONProducer()

    api.CompanyAddCompanyHandler = company.AddCompanyHandlerFunc(func(params company.AddCompanyParams) middleware.Responder {
        //log.Debugf("Add commpay Handler Called")
        //log.Infof("Payload Data : %v", params.Body)

        response, err := handlers.AddCompany(params)
        if err != nil {
            return company.NewAddCompanyBadRequest().WithPayload(&models.ErrorReponse400{
                Error: err.Error(),
            })
        }

        return company.NewAddCompanyCreated().WithPayload(response)
    })
```

And here is my implementation of the the `AddCompany` func.

```
package handlers

import (
    "hairdoo.com/m/v2/db"
    "hairdoo.com/m/v2/models"
    "hairdoo.com/m/v2/restapi/operations/company"
)

func AddCompany(params company.AddCompanyParams) (*models.Company, error) {
    result, err := db.AddCompany(params.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return result, nil
}
```

And finally the db packages implementation

```
package db

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "hairdoo.com/m/v2/models"
)

type Company struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name           string `gorm:"uniqueIndex"`
    Phone          string
    Email          string
    ContatctPerson string
    CategoryID     int
    Category       *Category
    Status         string
}

type Category struct {
    ID   int
    Name string `gorm:"uniqueIndex"`
}

func AddCompany(companyObj *models.Company) (*models.Company, error) {
    db := Open()
    var result *gorm.DB

    category := &Category{}

    db.Where("name = ?", companyObj.Category.Name).First(category)

    company := convertToDBCompany(companyObj, false)
    if category.ID != 0 {
        result = db.Exec("INSERT INTO companies (created_at, updated_at, name, phone, email, contatct_person, category_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);",
            time.Now(), time.Now(), companyObj.Name, companyObj.Phone, companyObj.Email, companyObj.ContatctPerson, category.ID)
    } else {
        result = db.Create(company)
    }

    if result.RowsAffected < 1 {
        return nil, result.Error
    }

    // add employee to db if object present
    var employees []*models.EmployeeItems0
    if companyObj.Employee != nil {
        for _, employeeInput := range companyObj.Employee {
            result, err := AddEmployee(employeeInput)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            employees = append(employees, result)
        }
    }

    return convertToModelCompany(company, employees), nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is to create a struct, which stores the db connection and put methods on this struct, for example:

```golang
type dbService struct {
    *gorm.DB
}

func InitDB() *dbService {
    db, err := gorm.Open(...)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Category{}, &Company{})
    return &dbService{db}
}

func (db *dbService) AddCompany(companyObj *models.Company) (*models.Company, error) {
    company := convertToDBCompany(companyObj, false)

    db.FirstOrInit(company.Category, &Category{Name: companyObj.Category.Name})
    result := db.Create(&company)

    if result.RowsAffected < 1 {
        return nil, result.Error
    }
 
   ...
}
```

and if you are using gorm already, I would suggest you to take actual advantage of its ORM functionalities ;)

Answer (score 2):

You certainly do not want to be connecting to the db with every request as Gorm (and the underlying db libraries) implement connection pooling to transparently reuse connections across multiple requests, and reconnecting every time completely undoes all that hard work.

Overall the idea is that you need to first initialize your application to get it ready to answer requests as fast as possible.

### Global with static init

One options is to do configuration and initialization statically at the package level:

db/db.go

```golang
package db

import (
    "os"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
)

var DB *gorm.DB

func init() {
    DB, err = gorm.Open(sqlite.Open(os.Getenv("SQLITE_DB")), &gorm.Config{})
    // error handling
}
```

`init` runs automatically, and thereafter any other package can access `db.DB` as a global object to run queries.

### Global with coordinated init

It's usually better to have more control of when the db gets initialized, as it might depend on values that must themselves be initialized (configuration file must be read, for example). In this case you would rename `init` to `Init` (or anything else really) and then call that function from a `main` or other setup function that orchestrates the apps initialization. In `go-swagger` with the standard template, that can be done in the `configureAPI` function.

```golang
func configureAPI(api *operations.HairdooAPI) http.Handler {
   // ...
   db.Init(...)
   
   // ... setup handlers
}
```

After that, you should be able to access the opened and ready `db.DB` global from your other db functions like `AddCompany`.

### Dependency injection style

The above should be enough to answer your question; as your app grows larger you might consider a different architectural style where you don't depend on a global variable, which makes your code hard to test. This is somewhat like what `joelazar` suggests, each handler or service is a struct that has a `*gorm.DB` field, that field gets set in the init process. To illustrate:

```golang
package handlers

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Company struct {
    DB *gorm.DB
}

func (h *Company) AddCompany(models.Company, ...) ... {
    h.DB.Foo()
}
```

```golang
func configureAPI(api *operations.HairdooAPI) http.Handler {

    dbHandler := db.Init(...)
    companyHandler := handlers.Company{DB: dbHandler}
    ...

    api.CompanyAddCompanyHandler = company.AddCompanyHandlerFunc(func(params company.AddCompanyParams) middleware.Responder {
        response, err := companyHandler.AddCompany(params)
        ...
    }
}
```

There's much more to be said about this kind of setup. With `go-swagger` I found [the stratoscale templates](https://github.com/Stratoscale/swagger) useful for generating an architecture that's less coupled and more testable. Something to consider for the longer term.